# Should the network interface gateway be 255.255.255.255?

Tags: networking

On a private network I'm using, I'm configuring the ethernet interface as such:

```
IP address : 192.168.1.10
Net mask  : 255.255.255.0
Gateway   : 255.255.255.255
```

I can understand the first 2, but the gateway value didn't make sense to me. It should be the router's address, right?

Comment: @cwd: what are you saying?

Comment: i think it's pretty clear. you should at least put a more accurate question title in...

Comment: typically your gateway in a situation like that would be 192.168.1.1

Comment: yes, it should be the router's address in most situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gateway should be the IP address of the device your computer will go to when it needs to communicate outside of your local network, eg your router. 255.255.255.255 is a broadcast address and has no chance of working.

Comment: that's what I thought. but that's the working value, at least that's what I was told.

Comment: it will work for local addresses, If your successfully using it on the internet I have no Idea how its doing it.